# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{a-1} i = \frac{a(a-1)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm pretty sure $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{a-1} i = \frac{a(a-1)}{2}$$ using the relationship $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

It looks similar to $$\sum\limits_{i=a}^{n} i = \frac{(n+a)(n-a+1)}{2}$$ but I'm not sure how or why does$$\sum\limits_{i=a}^{n} i = \frac{(n+a)(n-a+1)}{2}?$$

Comment: It's the sum of an arithmetic progression. There are $n-a+1$ terms, and the average term is $\frac12(a+n)$.

Comment: not sure what you mean? Can you show the substitution to get the result?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Ure taking the first and last term added together divided by 2 multiplied by the number of terms

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sum_A^B=\sum_1^B - \sum_1^{A-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{i=a}^{n} i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i-  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{a-1} i$$

Now substitute and subtract.